Gantt Visual Hide tooltip values that are null
I have been using Davide Bacci Deneb gantt visual and I have a question: is it possible to hide tooltip values that are null..
so if for example there are no '#Risks' then this tooltip value doesn't show on the tooltip.
also with items missing dates it defaults to a 1969 date, can this be configured to show null.
online searches and helpers

Can you supply a .pbix with data illustrating the issue?
